# error writing to plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

```
[array writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist" atomically:YES];
```

this line gives error that method `-stringByAppendingPathComponent` not found. whats the issue

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"First", @"Second", @"Third", nil];
[array writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist" atomically:YES]];
```

Comment: You forgot a ']' and please format your code.

Comment: You also forgot to include the rest of the code which would give this line some context. What is documentsDirectory and how do you derive it?

Comment: no mats it was a copy paste issue, i am still having the same problem

Comment: NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"First", @"Second", @"Third", nil];
    [array writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist" atomically:YES]];

Comment: sorry i know its hard to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 

plistpath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Product.plist"]];
```

And then

```
[array writeToFile:path atomically:YES]; 

[Whatever [Array or Dictionary] you want to Write in Plist]
```

If it is still not creating the plist then check whether your array or dictionary must be empty.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by Mats in comments, but seemingly ignored (or incorrectly corrected by you in the edit):

```
[array writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist" atomically:YES]];
```

Should be

```
[array writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"] atomically:YES];
```

Note the positioning of the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",documentsDirectory);

    NSString *plistName = @"%@chores.plist";
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:plistName];

    NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"abc",@"pqr",@"xyz",nil];
[array writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```