# iOS plist can't load data fom plist but works on simulator

Tags: ios, xml, load, plist, tableview

```
-(NSString*)dataFilePath{        
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ProperyList.plist"];
}
```

The iDevice can't load data form this path, only the simulator can.

Comment: what is the string that is returned from **dataFilePath**

Comment: If everything like path is correct then it might be issue of case sensitivity of file name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489522/stringbyappendingpathcomponent-hows-it-work

Comment: Omar, here's the string:

  2012-06-21 09:58:26.015 Everything[14249:f803] /Users/Lucas/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/431BB256-0B69-49DE-A9AE-A78B822572E3/Documents/PropertyList.plist
2012-06-21 09:58:26.016 <MyAppName>[14249:f803]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `NSLog` your `dataFilePath` value returned from this method and then check either the plist file (PropertyList.plist) exists at your document directory or not. Use the following code to check this :

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dataFilePath];
```

You must also confirm whether you are you using the correct file name. iOS devices are case sensitive while simulator is not.

Comment: I got a NULL. I guess it means the file isn't there... Well, is there another way to detect plists created in Xcode?

Comment: Are you creating the plist programmatically in your code and then storing it in document directory? Please check if you are using correct code to do this? And also do you get

Comment: Browse or go to this location/path in your system  /Users/Lucas/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/431BB256-0B69-49DE-A9AE-A78B822572E3/Documents/Proper‌​tyList.plist and check the PropertyList you created exists at this path or not.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309761/error-writing-to-plist)   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754668/can-not-find-plist-file-in-documents-directory-how-to-modify-the-plist-programa)